# Return all documents containing a certain field with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My schema has a string field `companyName` in my document.
I get an object from the query string as `{companyName:"Amazon,Microsoft"}}`.
How do I get back all documents that have company name either Amazon or Microsoft?

Right now I am changing the object to `{companyName:{$regex:"Amazon Microsoft",$options:'i'}}` and passing it to `find()` method but it is returning an empty array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform your query string into [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```
let query = {companyName:"Amazon,Microsoft"};

let mongoDbQuery = { companyName: { $in: query.companyName.split(',') } }

let result = await Model.find(mongoDbQuery);
```